# Can't access grub on Ubuntu HP laptop

Tags: 22.04, grub-efi

I have a HP laptop with only Ubuntu in it and I want to access grub. When I spam <kbd>Shift</kbd> nothing pops up. When I click <kbd>Esc</kbd> I get to HP BIOS/UEFI. What can I do?

Comment: You may use ESC right after the time is up to access the firmware. You may want to disable Fast Boot in UEFI.

Comment: @ChanganAuto could you be more specific? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Open the UEFI settings and disable Fast Boot. This will allow it an extra second between the time the ESC key works for the HP special menu and the time right before Grub starts loading, But the question is why do you think you need the Grub menu if only booting Ubuntu?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I want to use grub to get into safe mode. Anyways, I didn't see a quick boot option but I found an option that gives you some seconds more before the boot. I then saved and quit and started spamming shift again but nothing. Is there something else to press?

Comment: There's no safe mode. There are advanced options to boot an older kernel. As expected this is a X-Y problem. What problems exactly are you trying to solve? It's a good idea to ask about those and not about what you think is a solution (and very likely isn't).

Comment: @ChanganAuto I forgot my password cause I had the brilliant idea to change it and I am following this guide https://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-reset-forgotten-ubuntu-password/

Comment: Do you have backups of your personal files, don't you? Because if not their lost either way. And if you have then just reinstall Ubuntu (and don't forget the password).

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have back ups to google drive using the build in app but I was having hopes if I could prevent the loss

Comment: You can't. Even after successfully changing the password with that hack it won't allow access to the old files. That's why passwords exist!

Comment: Welp thanks for the help @ChanganAuto. Guess it's time for the inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

As you’re booting your computer, wait for the manufacturer logo to flash from the BIOS.
If your computer boots too quickly, you’re going to need to do this immediately after powering it on. Quickly press either the `Shift` or `Escape` key. On newer computers, it’s probably `Escape`. The timing has to be near perfect on some computers, so you may have to press it repeatedly. If you miss the window, `Ctrl + Alt + Del` and try again.